# Can I use SQLParameter when having a variable quantity of fields to update?

Tags: ado.net

I have a table with eighty fields, none to seventy of them can change depending of an update process I have.  For example:

```
if (process.result == 1)
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE T SET f1=1, f6='S'" ;
else if (Process.result == 2)
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("UPDATE T SET f1=2, f12={0},f70='{1}'", getData(), st);
else if ..... etc.
```

I can optimize the building process of the UPDATE statement, however I would like to use  **SQLParameter**; is that possible and convenient given the variablity of data to update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For each if statement you currently are using inline string formats, you could just as well just add the sql params instead.

The formatting of the *UPDATE* string could be replaced with the selected sql params you require to be updated insted.

Comment: astander, I understand that the key with SQL parameters is to create a command text only once, for example in the way "UPDATE ... SET f1=?, f2=?,....,f70=?", but my problem is that not all the fields will need to be updated; may be for one record no update is needed or, for another, only the last ten fields will need to be updated, and so on.